# Keeping the bottom of your legs warm in very-cold-weather biking

Tags: winter, clothes, weather

I come from a country with a warmer climate,but am now living in the Netherlands. It's not that bad really, but in winter, it sometimes gets to -5°c / -6°c - and occasionally with strong head wind when I cycle to work. I'm also very sensitive to the cold, and can catch a cold very easily, so I need to cover up. I'm wearing street clothes, rather than cycling-specific gear.

Now, I'm doing that well enough - for the most part: Gloves, balaclava, winter coat with a head piece, wind-and-rain overpants (is that a word?), gloves and well-insulated shoes. So, I mostly stay nice and warm.

There's one problematic spot though: Where my shoe ends and my pant-like clothing begins:

- None of it is long enough to "grip" the shoe, nor do I think I want it to be.
- It's a shoe, not a boot (and I dislike boots); so not long enough to tuck the pants inside the boot/shoe.
- If I wore two pairs of socks, one on top of the other, I would have a hard time fitting my foot into my shoe.

What do you do, or what would you suggest, to keep that tricky area warmer?

Comment: Have you tried shoe covers? Some are longer than others. Also two very thin pairs of socks can be warmer than one thick pair

Comment: Check out "gaiters" at an outdoor clothing place.

Comment: Are you sure your shoes are big enough? I often wear 3 pairs of socks (including a set of long football socks) and over-shoes.

Comment: @ChrisH: Won't a shoe cover give me trouble cycling and walking?

Comment: Cycling shoe covers are a bit like gaiters but closer fitting. Many have some insulation value but some are just water- and wind-proof. Most, but by no means all, are optimised for clipless pedals. I commute in MTB shoes, and my shoe covers do reduce grip under my toes when walking, but the reason I prefer to take them off when not riding is to avoid wearing them out.

Comment: This seems pretty extreme for -6 C.

Comment: @Batman that sounds a little too much for me at -6 even with wind chill at 50km/h downhill, but I see plenty of people commuting in that much even slightly above freezing.  People vary a lot.

Comment: @Batman: I can catch a could from riding without my balaclava even when it's 10°c.

Comment: There really should be an answer that involves duct tape.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus If you think the asker hasn't already tried all possible duct tape solutions, you should downvote for not "show[ing] any research effort". ;-)

Comment: Actually, I think that longer pants are the way to go. If you are wearing jeans that are just above the ground when standing straight, they will protect your ankles just fine when cycling. The heavy cotton breaks the wind just fine, allowing your socks to properly insulate your ankles. At least that's my experience.

Comment: As I see it, none of the replies mentions active heating. There are heating pads that work by burning / oxidizing iron mixed with carbon. These are one time and used when their package is opened. Others use heat from a liquid-solid phase transition, which you can start by clicking a metal plate within the liquid. To reload, you just heat or boil the plastic package until the solid returns to liquid. However: you should not exert too much pressure on the plastic bags and they are voluminous. Here, an electric heating system is the more convenient and pricey alternative among reloadable systems.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest shoe covers, which look like a boot and cover the ankle.

Or wear mid-calf or knee length socks and roll the upper part down for double or triple coverage on the ankles.

Or, [mini ankle warmers](https://www.etsy.com/market/ankle_warmers) :-).

Pics of my Pearl Izumi MTB overboots. The sole is exposed so walking is possible. (Not a product recommendation, just what I happen to own.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would think that leg warmers will suffice for your situation. They come in different sizes(width) and generally cover from the top of the shoe up to the middle of the calf. I wear them a lot in cold weather since I suffer from cold feet and hands due to thyroid disease since I was a teen and ended up having both types of the disease when I was a teen. It took me years to find them since there was no internet then; you should have no problem accessing a supplier now. The really neat thing about them is that you can wear more than one pair at a time and yes, they do make them for men.

Comment: Agreed.  I have two sizes of legwarmers - one are full length ankle to top-of-thigh and work well with bib shorts and shoe covers for full protection.  The others are shin length only and hang around the top of the calf muscle, then go down to the top of the shoe.

Answer (score 2):

**Wear skiing socks**

- They are long enough to cover the legs below the kneelings
- They are very warm
- They fit into most shoes if they are not overly tight
- They often offer some protection
- There are some in bright colors, what makes them great for visibility
- They or similarly long and thick socks are very popular amongst bicycle messengers

Comment: The sock length is not much of an issue, but sock width might be relevant to look into. As for bright colors and visibility - this is Amsterdam, that's not an issue. Roads are populated by bikes on the bike lanes, you don't need any visibility for that.

Comment: Also if you have long socks and only a small bit to cover you can fold them over so the notmal upper end aligns with the upper end of your shoes

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go cheap, you could just take a pair of socks and cut off the foot or even half the foot, if fit into the shoe is the problem.  Then wear this over your ankle and part-way down into the shoe.  I like the idea of improvisational engineering so this works for me.  I do something similar for my wrists, although in that case it goes all the way to my fingers.  Toasty warm.

I have a pair of gaiters from backpacking but I hadn't thought of that, I'll try that next time.  I bet that'll be great.  Those shoe covers and overboots look great too.

I went though some plantar fasciitis.  To fix this (along with stretching) I got custom orthotics which mandated bigger shoes, and I got them big enough to wear two pair of socks all the time.  That alone is enough to keep my ankles warm on all but the coldest days.

Answer (score 1):

Wear "kniekousen", i.e. socks that go up to your knee.

Comment: How would that help? Your ankles would still only be covered by one layer of material.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange.  Your answer is a good start but needs a lot more information to be useful.  Adding a photo or two can help show what you mean.  Also add how it works for you, and the advantages and disadvantages of long socks.  I guess they're not particularly wind resistant.  How do they go in the wet/snow ?   Wool or cotton or some other fabric?  You can use the "edit" link below your answer to expand it.

Comment: I don't think that socks will help much: To protect limbs from cold while cycling, you need to protect them from the **wind**. Socks are typically not made out of wind-proof material; a thin jeans provides much more protection than any sock I would like to wear.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for are *Snow Ski Leg Covers* or *Gaiters*. It's a waterproof and windproof thing that covers your legs from under the heel up to mid-thigh. The good ones also have a little hook in front that's attached to the lacing of your shoes.

This really works wonders for ankle thermal comfort. I'm not sure how easy it is to get ski equipment in the Netherlands in general though.

Comment: People use gaiters when hiking, so the lack of... um... skiing tradition in the Netherlands may not be a problem.